# On pressing hardware back button my app should navigate to first tab from second tab

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3, back-button

I have two tabs in my app, let's say tab1 and tab2. If I am currently in tab2 then on pressing back button I should go to tab1 instead of closing my app.

Comment: Check out this guide: https://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-3-how-to-manage-hardware-back-button-event-like-a-pro/

Answer (score 0):

You can check in which tab you are by adding addOnPageChangeListener and in onPageScrolled method you can check whether it is the first tab or page or second tab and store that as boolean or flag variable. Then override the onBackPressed method and use an if condition using that flag variable and accordingly call super.onBackPressed if it's the first tab or else just call return